# Unable to stop delayed_jobs in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I see in my log that delayed_job is continuously running, and I can't get it to stop. I've already tried 'rake jobs:clear' to no avail.

Here is what the log looks like:

```
 Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.2ms)  
 UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2013-02-21 16:01:18.602988', locked_by = 'host:computer.local pid:2343' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2013-02-21 16:01:18.602333' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2013-02-21 12:01:18.602367') OR locked_by = 'host:computer.local pid:2343') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

Comment: it seems that foreman (with unicorn) is somehow causing this, since when i try webrick, it does not happen

Answer (score 1):

You need to kill it:

```
    pkill -9 -f delayed_job
```

`rake jobs:clear` will clear the jobs which are in `queue`. It won't stop the `delayed_job`.

Comment: what you mean?? Do `pgrep -f delayed_job` on your terminal.

Comment: the pgrep did not return anything

Comment: If `pgrep -f delayed_job` returns nothing that means `you have no delayed_job running`. If delayed_job is running it will return process `id`.

Comment: thanks for your help. i guess now i will try to figure out what is outputting those logs

Comment: i understand now that i didn't understand how delayed_job works - it is constantly checking for new jobs, and i didn't set a sleep_delay, so it kept going without pause. now that i have set the sleep_delay, (60 seconds), it only checks every minute.